# Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack

Tags: java, playframework

Tengo un error al correr el play framework, me sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El error es la clase:**

```
/**
 * Método que extrae todas las palabras clave de los nodos que conforman el diagrama
 * @return HashMap Estructura con los listados de palabras clava de cada nodo
 */
private HashMap<Integer,List<KeyWord>> getNodeKeyWords(){

    HashMap<Integer,List<KeyWord>> nodeKeys = new HashMap<Integer,List<KeyWord>>() ;
    List<KeyWord> keys = new ArrayList<KeyWord>() ;

    for( Regla r : reglas ){

        if( r.estado == 0 ) continue ;
        r.fillNodes() ;
        keys = new ArrayList<KeyWord>() ;
        if( r.nodosi.keyWords != null ) for( KeyWord k : r.nodosi.keyWords ) keys.add( k ) ;
        nodeKeys.put( r.nodosi.idnodo ,  keys ) ;
        keys = new ArrayList<KeyWord>() ;
        if( r.nodoentonces.keyWords != null ) for( KeyWord k : r.nodoentonces.keyWords ) keys.add( k ) ;
        nodeKeys.put( r.nodoentonces.idnodo ,  keys ) ;
    }
    return nodeKeys ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo que estas dando muy poca información. **¿Podría estar el error en el método `fillNodes()`?**

Yo sospecho que quizás el problema este en los nodos ya que no hace ninguna comprobación, y no sé si es necesaria porque sabemos muy poco de tus clases.

Te recomiendo que amplies tu problema y sobretodo que hagas más legible tu código, no importa que se ocupe el triple de líneas de código, lo que de verdad importa es que se puede leer y entender lo más fácil posible.

Hubiera preferido ponerlo como un comentario a tu pregunta pero mi reputación aún no llega ;(